# How to add @Link on test case failure in Allure report

Tags: testing, allure

The scenario is this that we are maintaining a separate list of existing test failures and if that test fails again we want to add @Link in the allure report to that particular test case with the @link message picked from that separate list.

It is possible by adding @link annotation to the code itself but is it possible to provide link on failed test cases in allure report after the test failure?

Answer (score 2):

Allure provide access to it's Lifecycle class and class with helper methods which can help you add links to test cases dynamically from the code. Here is the code snippet:

```
@TmsLink("SO-1")
@Test
public void addLinkInTest() throws Exception{
    boolean testFailed = true;
    if(testFailed){
        Allure.addLinks(new Link()
                .withName("STACKOVERFLOW LINK")
                .withUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941193/how-to-add-link-on-test-case-failure-in-allure-report"));
    }
}
```

You can make this call from test method or put it into [ITestListener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) in `onTestFailure()` method

Here is how result will look like:
[image]